# Navigation Drawer and MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I'd like to know what is the correct approach to implement a MapFragment with a navigation drawer. I already had this working fine, but I have been reading some documentation and maybe it can cause troubles in the future.

So, my main class where the navigation drawer has been implemented is a very normal one, with the following `selectItem()` method:

```
HomeActivity extends Activity{

//...
//Stuff like onCreate(), etc.
//...

private void selectItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {  //Position 0 is the map option in the navigationDrawer
        Fragment fragment = new MapaFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(listaElementosDrawer[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

MapaFragment, which is the inflated fragment in the main activity, is as follows:

```
public class MapaFragment extends Fragment {

public MapaFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

And, `fragment_map.xml` which is inflated in `MapaFragment` is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.moictab.decanias.MapActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that this is a mapFragment inside of a RelativeLayout, and it is already working well. But, if I remove the RelativeLayout and I left only the mapFragment, it crashes cause I'm inflating a fragment inside of a fragment. So, there is the questions:

- Why does it crash when it inflates the mapFragment but it does NOT crash when inflating the RelativeLayout with the mapFragment inside? Isn't it essentially the same?
- What is the correct approach to implement something like that?

Comment: Did you find anything? any approach?

Comment: Nothing at all, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a very simmilar problem with MapFragment. This is my solution:

I extend SupportMapFragment object:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFramgment
{

}
```

and add it programatically:

```
MyMapFragment fragment = new MyMapFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: what is content_frame here?

Comment: this is layout id to place your map fragment